# Macro only stores part of the string

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I create my variable like this:

```
data Concat_var; 
    Table_periode_MDR = CAT("\\Afdeling\HS-OKO\Oko\Likviditet\Likviditetsstyring\LCR\Indberetning\2022\",&Periode,"\RLI\Output_Daglig_LCR\MDR_korrektion.csv"); 
    Table_periode_Dagligkorr = CAT("\Afdeling\HS-OKO\Oko\Likviditet\Likviditetsstyring\LCR\Indberetning\2022\",&Periode,"\RLI\Månedlig_LCR_RLI\WORK_QUERY_FOR_DAGLIGEKORREKTIONER.csv");
    Table_periode_weights_m = CAT("\Afdeling\HS-OKO\Oko\Likviditet\Likviditetsstyring\LCR\Indberetning\2022\",&Periode,"\RLI\Månedlig_LCR_RLI\Weights_M.csv");
    Table_periode_weights_d = CAT("\Afdeling\HS-OKO\Oko\Likviditet\Likviditetsstyring\LCR\Indberetning\2022\",&Periode,"\RLI\Output_Daglig_LCR\Weights_D.csv");
    Table_periode_W_D_LCR = CAT("\Afdeling\HS-OKO\Oko\Likviditet\Likviditetsstyring\LCR\Indberetning\2022\",&Periode,"\RLI\Output_Daglig_LCR\W_D_LCR.csv");
    Table_periode_W_M_LCR = CAT("\Afdeling\HS-OKO\Oko\Likviditet\Likviditetsstyring\LCR\Indberetning\2022\",&Periode,"\RLI\Månedlig_LCR_RLI\W_M_LCR.csv");
run;

PROC SQL NOPRINT;

SELECT DISTINCT 
          Table_periode_MDR,
          Table_periode_Dagligkorr,
          Table_periode_weights_m,
          Table_periode_weights_d,
          Table_periode_W_D_LCR,
          Table_periode_W_M_LCR


INTO      :Table_periode_MDR,
          :Table_periode_Dagligkorr,
          :Table_periode_weights_m,
          :Table_periode_weights_d,
          :Table_periode_W_D_LCR,
          :Table_periode_W_M_LCR

FROM Concat_var;
```

When looking in the "Concat_var" everything looks right.

The issue is that when I use the string to import files like this:

```
proc import datafile=&Table_periode_MDR
        out=MDR_korrektion
        replace
        dbms=csv 
        replace;
        getnames=yes;
        delimiter=';';
run;
```

But I get an error because the string is only:

```
\Afdeling\HS-OKO\Oko\Likviditet\Likviditetsstyring\LCR\Indberetning\2022\202208\RLI\Output_Daglig_LCR\MDR_ko
```

How can I get the whole string when I create my variable?

I hope you can point me in the right direction.

Comment: How is &period created?

Comment: By a promt in SAS EG

Comment: You did not define a length for the variables in the data step.  Make sure you define them long enough for the value you want to assign.  Why do you have both the data step and the sql step?  Why not just make the macro variables using CALL SYMPUTX() in the data step and skip the SQL step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cat()` automatically sets the variable length to 200, and your text is within that range so that does not appear to be the issue.

Although I cannot directly recreate your results, consider creating your macro variables directly. You do not need to use a separate data step with a SQL :into to concatenate them. The macro processor automatically knows where macro variables start and end with `&` and `.`

```
%let folder = \\Afdeling\HS-OKO\Oko\Likviditet\Likviditetsstyring\LCR\Indberetning\2022\;

%let Table_periode_MDR        = &folder.\&periode.\RLI\Output_Daglig_LCR\MDR_korrektion.csv;
%let Table_periode_Dagligkorr = &folder.\&periode.\RLI\Månedlig_LCR_RLI\WORK_QUERY_FOR_DAGLIGEKORREKTIONER.csv;
%let Table_periode_weights_m  = &folder.\&periode.\RLI\Månedlig_LCR_RLI\Weights_M.csv;
%let Table_periode_weights_d  = &folder.\&periode.\RLI\Månedlig_LCR_RLI\Weights_M.csv;
%let Table_periode_W_D_LCR    = &folder.\&periode.\RLI\Output_Daglig_LCR\W_D_LCR.csv;
%let Table_periode_W_M_LCR    = &folder.\&periode.\RLI\Månedlig_LCR_RLI\W_M_LCR.csv;
```